# Rails 3 taking a long time to load the results

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

My rails application has to query through a database which has lacks of rows and display the matching results. My code is working perfectly but its dead slow ,its taking a very long time to show the results.I am using  ruby 1.9.3 and rails 3.2.13 and "Webrick" server.I am sure there is some problem . Is there any way I can resolve this .I have two tables called coordinates and tweets.

My code for the controller

```
require 'will_paginate/array'
class TweetsController<ApplicationController
  def index
    city = params[:show]
    search_term = params[:text]

    search_term.gsub!(/\s/, '%')
    city_coordinates = Coordinates.where('city=?', city)

     if (city_coordinates.count == 1 && city_coordinates.first.valid_location?)
       @tweets = ((Tweets.for_coordinates(city_coordinates.first) &  Tweets.where("tweet_text LIKE?" , "%#{search_term}%"))).paginate(page: params[:page], per_page:5)
     elsif(city_coordinates.count!=1)
       @tweets  =   ((Tweets.for_user_location(city) &  Tweets.where("tweet_text LIKE?" , "%#{search_term}%"))).paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 5)
     else
       Tweets.where("tweet_text LIKE? ", "%#{search_term}%").paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 5)
     end
  end
end
```

My code for the model

```
class Tweets<ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible  :id, :tweet_created_at, :tweet_id, :tweet_text, :tweet_source, :user_id, :user_name, :user_sc_name, :user_loc, :user_img, :longitude, :latitude, :place, :country
  def self.for_coordinates(coordinates)
    bbox = { min_lat: coordinates.latitude - 1.0, max_lat: coordinates.latitude + 1.0,
      min_lng: coordinates.longitude - 1.0, max_lng: coordinates.longitude + 1.0
    }
    Tweets.where("(longitude BETWEEN ? and ?) AND (latitude BETWEEN ? and ?) OR (user_loc LIKE ?) " ,
                 bbox[:min_lng], bbox[:max_lng], bbox[:min_lat], bbox[:max_lat], "%#{coordinates.city}%" )
  end

  def self.for_user_location(city)
    @tweets= Tweets.where("user_loc LIKE ?", "%#{city}%")                
  end
end
```

My code for the view

```
<%= will_paginate @tweets %>
<% @tweets.each do |tweets| %>
<ul>
  <li><%= tweets.id %></li>
  <li><%= tweets.tweet_created_at %></li>

  <li><%= tweets.tweet_source %></li>
  <li><%= tweets.tweet_text %></li>
  <li><%= tweets.user_id %></li>
  <li><%= tweets.user_name %></li>
  <li><%= tweets.user_sc_name %></li>
<li><%= tweets.user_loc %></li>
  <li><%= tweets.user_img %></li>
  <li><%= tweets.longitude %></li>
  <li><%= tweets.latitude %></li>
<li><%= tweets.place %></li>
  <li><%= tweets.country %></li>

<% end %>
</ul>
```

It has two search boxes ,one for the tweet query and another for the city,It has to display tweets for a particular city.But its very slow .I am not able to find the  reason if it is due to inefficient coding or wrong choice of server or some other reasons .It uses Mysql database.

Comment: It seems you are doing lots of search based on geolocation and full-text. RDBMSs are not the right candidates for these operations. You can try using Solr/Sphinx for full text searching. Geolocation queries are slower (for obvious reasons). You can consider making the right indexes in database for this table, which will help

Comment: Are you sure that this is a rails problem? You are performing a `LIKE '%term%'` query, which always results in a full table scan in relational databases. Did you create indexes for the geoloc parts of the queries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is with the union of two queries:

```
@tweets = (
  (
    Tweets.for_coordinates(city_coordinates.first) & 
    Tweets.where("tweet_text LIKE?" , "%#{search_term}%")
  )
).paginate(page: params[:page], per_page:5)
```

What this does is:

1. Retrieve all tweets for the city coordinates into an in-memory array
2. Retrieve all tweets where the text matches the search term into an in-memory array
3. Concatenates the arrays from 1. and 2.
4. Paginates these results

What you want to do instead is:

1. Filter for tweets that match the city coordinates AND the search term
2. Paginate the results
3. Retrieve the paginated results

You'll want something more like this:

```
@tweets = Tweets.for_coordinates(city_coordinates.first).
  where('tweet_text like ?', "%#{search_term}%").
  paginate(page:params[:page], per_page:5)
```